# How can I set an individual checkbox in a checkbox group to "checked" based on it's value attr?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, attributes

```
 <div id="notifydaydiv" name="notifydaydiv" style="display:none; padding-left:50px">
 <input name="notifyday" type="checkbox" value="wed" /> Wednesday <br />
 <input name="notifyday" type="checkbox" value="thu" /> Thursday <br />
 <span style="color:red; font-size:7pt;">Recommended</span><br />
 <input name="notifyday" type="checkbox" value="fri" checked="checked"/> Friday 
 <div id="day_err"></div>
 <script>
  [ set which checkbox is checked based on the value attr ]
 </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Once the user checks one of the checkboxes, the value set is the same as the checkbox that was checked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find and check it using the [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), like this:

```
$(":checkbox[value='wed']").attr('checked', true);
```

You can also use `name` in there if needed, like this:

```
$(":checkbox[name='notifyday'][value='wed']").attr('checked', true);
```

Comment: Beat you by five very solid seconds...!

Comment: @Deniz - Almost ;) You should use `true` or `false` here, that's the way it's normalized, e.g. `.att('checked') === true` :)

Comment: @Deniz - Not sure actually, something you learn along the way I guess.  No specifics in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), just this: **Cross-browser consistency:** Some attributes have inconsistent naming from browser to browser. Furthermore, the values of some attributes are reported inconsistently across browsers, and even across versions of a single browser. The `.attr()` method reduces such inconsistencies.

Comment: I like the use of name here.  Seems more clear.  So Deniz you're saying it should look like this: 
$(":checkbox[name='notifyday'][value='wed']").attr('checked') === true  ??

Comment: @isuelt - `.attr('checked')` *gets* the value, it would be `true` if checked, `false` if not, but you can also use that to *set* the value, e.g. `.attr('checked', true)` to check or `.attr('checked', false)` to uncheck.

Comment: Nowadays better to use `.prop('checked', true)` instead of `.attr('checked', true)`. You get some funky behavior with the latter if you check/uncheck multiple times. https://jsfiddle.net/gsj5o3j6/50/

Answer (score 2):

```
$(":checkbox[value='wed']").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

For more information, see the [JQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(":checkbox[value='wed']").attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

Make sure that the page is loaded before you try and check the checkbox.